# Append large block of HTML with variables in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

I have a for loop which is iterating over some JSON data and for each JSON object I need to output a large block of HTML which will look like this:

```
<div class="hotel-result independent">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="hotel-type"><span class="independent">Independent Garage</span></div>
    <h3>Hotel Name</h3>
    <div class="meta-info">
      <span class="distance">
        <i class="fonticon-map-marker"></i>
        1.6 miles from N1 2NL
      </span>
      <span class="telephone hidden-xs">
        <i class="fonticon-telephone2"></i>
        92358023523
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="service">Room</div>
      <div class="price-wrap">
        <span class="currency">£</span>
        <span class="price">30.95</span>
        <span class="vat small">inc VAT</span>
      </div>
      <a class="button teal has-icon-right" href="#">
        Book online
        <i class="fonticon-chevron-right"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="button light-grey has-icon-right phone-booking hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        Touch to call
        <i class="fonticon-telephone2"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Elements like Hotel Name, distance, postcode etc. need to be outputted from the JSON data.

I am trying to work out the best way of doing this as writing it out in pure javascript, document.createElement/ appendChild etc., seems quite long winded and I wondered if there is a better/cleaner method?

I have found other examples online but only where the amount of HTML is either very small or there is no need to pass data into the outputted HTML. Any advice would be much appreciated.

------- JSON Data Example -------

```
[{
  id: 0
  name: Hotel Name
  postcode: N1 2NL
  lat: latitude
  lng: Longitude
  hotel_type: independent 
  room_prices: [
    { id:35235325
      room_type: king
      room_price: 356.0
    }
    { id:23532523
      room_type: single
      room_price: 50.0
    }
  ]
}]
```

This is just a quick example of the kind of JSON.

Comment: Is the html pattern the same for each object from the parsed json collection? And what is the collection array , hash?

Comment: Also why pure js , you have added jQuery tag, you are using or not jquery?

Comment: @kidwon, The pattern is the same for every object yes with the exception that a few of the classes change. I.e above <div class="hotel-result independent"> could also be  <div class="hotel-result official"> depending on the kind of hotel in the result. I am indeed using jQuery so feel free to suggest a good jQuery method :)

Comment: Dependent on what **independent** and **official** classes are  ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON data please?

Comment: I've added an example of the data so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model` is your parsed json array

```
var pattern, nodes = $();
for(var i=0,size=model.length; i<size; i++){
  pattern = createHotelPattern(model[i]);
  nodes = nodes.add($(pattern));
};

$('#myNodeSelector').append(nodes);
```

Here's pattern creator:

```
  function createHotelPattern (data) {
    var pattern = [
      '<div class="hotel-result ',
      data.hotel_type,
      '">',
        '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">',
          '<div class="hotel-type">',
            '<span class="independent">Independent Garage</span>',
          '</div>',
          '<h3>',
            data.name,
          '</h3>',
          '<div class="meta-info">',
            '<span class="distance"> <i class="fonticon-map-marker"></i>',
              '1.6 miles from ', 
              data.postcode,
             '</span>',
            '<span class="telephone hidden-xs"> <i class="fonticon-telephone2"></i>',
              data.phone,
            '</span>',
          '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">',
          '<div class="service">',
            data.currency,
          '</div>',
          '<div class="price-wrap">',
            '<span class="currency">',
              data.room_type,
            '</span>',
            '<span class="price">',
              data.room_price,
            '</span>',
            '<span class="vat small">',
              'inc VAT',
             '</span>',
          '</div>',
          '<a class="button teal has-icon-right" href="#">',
            'Book online',
            '<i class="fonticon-chevron-right"></i>',
          '</a>',
          '<a href="" class="button light-grey has-icon-right phone-booking hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Touch to call<i class="fonticon-telephone2"></i></a>',
        '</div>',
      '</div>'
    ];

    return pattern.join('');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

There is a jQuery plugin called JSON2HTML that you could use.

Have a look at http://json2html.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try using any [javascript templating engine](http://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-templating-engines/) of your choice... Personally i really like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)